# how can i get English tweets only using java?

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

here the code

```
public void onStatus(Status status) {
String lang = status.getUser().getLang();
if (tweetCount < 50000) {
if (lang.equals("en")) {
storeInFile(status);
tweetCount++;
     }
    } 
}
```

tweets i get from all the languages. Is there a way to restrict myself to fetching tweets only in English?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you are using doesn't return the language of the tweet
Why don't you try:

```
status.getLang()
```

From [here](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/Status.html#getLang--):

> **Interface Status**
>
> java.lang.String getLang()
>
> Returns the lang of the status text if available.
>
> **Returns:**
>
> two-letter iso language code Since:
>       Twitter4J 3.0.6

Comment: thanks for replying ,but is this code status.getUser().getLang(); if (lang.equals("en"))  return users that names in english or what ?

Comment: can you check this link also if you can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28227730/how-to-restrict-twitter-api-request-to-tweets-in-english

Comment: Returns the preferred language of the user. From here: http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/User.html#getLang--

Comment: Are you using Streaming API or Rest API?

Comment: The code says, you are "streaming in" tweets. Read more about streaming API here: (https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview). BTW your another question seems same as this one! Before coding, gather knowledge of Twitter API

Comment: Sorry , when i tried i got this The method getLang() is undefined for the type Status

Comment: Check the twitter4j version you are using

Comment: i'm new in this . how can i check it ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Just download the latest stable version from twitter4j.org

Comment: really thanks for replying, is there any way to know what is the version of twitter4j i have ?

Comment: The JAR file is names as `twitter4j-core-X.X.X.jar` where X.X.X indicates version

Comment: Really , Many Thanks i solved it , if there is another accept answer button  i'll accept your answer twice, thanks again